# Check a complex unique constraint with Ecto

Tags: postgresql, elixir, constraints, ecto

In my Ecto schema, I have a **User** who `has_many` **Items**. An item has a boolean field **active**:

User module:

```
  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :items, Item
  end
```

Item module:

```
  schema "items" do
    field(:active, :boolean)
    belongs_to(:user, User)
  end
```

How can I ensure that a User has at most one item active? Thus, if a user already has an active item, the insertion of another active item should result in an error. The insertion of a new item with `active: false` should succeed, though.

It seems that [exclusion_constraint](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#exclusion_constraint/3) could be used for that, but I haven't found any docs showing how to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't describe your data model in any detail, but you can easily enforce such a condition on the database level if `items` has a foreign key to `users` (let's call it `user_id`). Then all you need is this partial unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON items (user_id) WHERE active;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from the tag that you're pointed at a Postgresql DB.  If so and if you've got the correct exclusion constraint coded then you can run any arbitrary SQL you want with [Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query/4](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#query/4) All you should need to do is to run the code to create the constraint once (probably in your seeds.exs script) and that should do it.